# Pros and cons in using multiple actor types in same Service Fabric service

Tags: actor, azure-service-fabric

When using the Azure Service Fabric Reliable Actor programming model, what are the pros and cons of using several actor types in the same service?
Is it only a matter of deployment, or are there runtime considerations as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pros:

- Increases density.
- Fewer projects to manage which is always helpful.

Cons:

- The actor types within the same package will have to be deployed/upgraded at the same time and are no longer independent.

My advice would be to use the same code packages if the various actors are quite tightly coupled logically.

Comment: I'd love an example of how you actually got about achieving multiple actor types within a single service.

Comment: Sorry John, I only just saw your comment. There's nothing particularly special about this - you just add many actor types in the same project/code package.